# Can there exist an arrangement of charge densities that creates a loop in the electric field lines of force?

Tags: electric-field, superconductors

**Can there exist an arrangement of charge densities that creates a loop in the electric field lines of force?**

In [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/598968/268467), a poster writes:

> Note 2 5/8: superconducting loop

> A uniformly perfectly conducting loop poses some extra problems because inside the perfectly conducting material there cannot be any resultant electric field Etot. This means that the surface charge will redistribute in such a way as to produce a coulombian field Ecoul that completely obliterates Eind everywhere inside the ring.

If no net electric field could exist within a superconductor, then the [London Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_equations), which reference the electric field within a superconductor would make no sense.

However, equally important is the fact that a fixed distribution of charge density cannot, no matter how arranged, bring about an electric field which contains a line of force which is a loop.

The electric field resulting from a distribution of charge density is conservative, and a conservative vector field cannot contain loops.

Since the electric field resulting from a distribution of charge density (what the poster refers to as the Coulombian field) cannot contain any loops, it cannot "completely obliterate" the electric field loops created by a time varying magnetic field.

Am I correct? Or incorrect?

Edit:

In a reply, @tobalt wrote:

> The London equations posit that there is no current in the bulk of the superconducting body. Therefore, it has to be free of both E field (otherwise current would build up) and B field

I agree that an E field in a superconductor will cause a time varying current. However, I would like to see a reference for the claim that "there is no current in the bulk of the superconducting body[, t]herefore, it has to be free of [an] E field"

[This paper](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.2929671), for example contradicts the notion that there cannot be an E field in the body of a superconductor.

> We show that a London superconductor in a steady uniform external magnetic field must support an electric field in its interior. The existence of an electric field implies that a superconductor has a nonvanishing charge in its interior, a fact consistent with measurements of charge imbalance in steady-state superconductivity.

See also: [this paper](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2002APS..MARA12009T/abstract), and [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/1938262_Charge_expulsion_and_electric_field_in_superconductors)

> As a consequence the superconductor in its ground state is predicted to have a non-homogeneous charge distribution and an outward pointing electric field in its interior.

@tobalt responded that:

> I just repeated what the London equations say. For magnetic field free interior, it would also be free of E field. It is also briefly mentioned in wiki below the introduction of the single London equation: A is zero in the bulk. Maybe that paper is referring to a nonideal situation, where there are non-SC volumes in the bulk, or where the magnetic field is present during the NC->SC transition and becomes eternally trapped.

I am not sufficiently knowledgeable at this point to determine whether the claimed E field within the body of a superconductors found in various papers *violates* or is *consistent with* the London Equations. So, I withdraw the claim that

> If no net electric field could exist within a superconductor, then the London Equations, which reference the electric field within a superconductor would make no sense.

However, the main issue that I wish to resolve is the claim made in the referenced answer that

> that the surface charge will redistribute in such a way as to produce a coulombian field Ecoul that completely obliterates Eind everywhere inside the ring.

I cannot see how a Coulomb field (an irrotational Electric field) could cancel a solenoidal/rotational Electric field, even if we restrict our attention to a single loop in the solenoid field.

Comment: @SredniVashtar please take a look at this question as it relates to your answer here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/598968/268467

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can there exist an arrangement of charge densities that creates a loop in the electric field lines of force?

## No.

This is easily seen as a direct consequence of Maxwell's laws, specifically Faraday's law of induction,

$$\nabla × \mathrm {\bf E} = -\frac{\partial \mathrm {\bf B}}{\partial t}$$

This states that the curl of the electric field must be zero in the absence of time-varying magnetic fields. If there is a loop in any field line, the curl must necessarily be nonzero near that loop.

As you are asking specifically about the case where there are only static charges, nothing can be time-varying, and so \$\nabla × \mathrm {\bf E} = \frac{\partial \mathrm {\bf B}}{\partial t} = 0\$ (not to mention the fact that only static charges implies that \$\mathrm{\bf B}\$ itself must also be zero).

Comment: Hope you don't mind. Repeated the question so it is clear what the "No" is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Maxwell says that you need a changing magnetic field to produce rot E. No static charge distribution will do this.

The London equations posit that there is no current in the bulk of the superconducting body. Therefore, it has to be free of both E field (otherwise current would build up) and B field

When subjecting a superconducting ring to a changing magnetic field (as per your linked question & answer), the Meissner Effect will prevent that changing magnetic field from reaching the interior of the ring. I.e. there is no rot E to be compensated by charge redistribution in the first place. All induced current flows on the surface of the superconductor in the London penetration depth zone. The interior of the SC is completely oblivious to anything happening outside.

Comment: I agree with your first statement. No static charge will produce a rotational E field. Would like to see a citation for second claim. See my edit, but stack exchange and quora answers aside, there are academic papers that contradict the idea that an E field cannot exist in the body of a superconductor.

Comment: I just repeated what the London equations say. For magnetic field free interior, it would also be free of E field. It is also briefly mentioned in wiki below the introduction of the single London equation: A is zero in the bulk. Maybe that paper is referring to a nonideal situation, where there are non-SC volumes in the bulk, or where the magnetic field is present during the NC->SC transition and becomes eternally trapped. Have you checked if that paper is being refuted by others citing it ?

Comment: A is not the electric field, but the vector potential.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy and A being zero mandates jS to be zero. if no current can exist, it also mandates that either no electric field can exist or that resistivity would be infinite (which is obviously false for a SC)

Comment: I need to study this further, but here is yet another reference to read. This time regarding the penetration depth of a magnetic field in a course about superconductors. https://www.open.edu/openlearn/science-maths-technology/engineering-technology/superconductivity/content-section-3.3

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy the penetration depth is a thin surface region in which the magnetic field is not yet fully cancelled and where all screening currents flow. But even there, currents are stationary (if the magnetic field is stationary) and so there will be no E field.

Comment: Yes, but there is a difference between saying that a quantity decays exponentially with distance, in which case it is always finite but non-zero, (even though small) and saying that the quantity is identically zero. In one case certain equations are _trivially_ true, and in the other case, the same equations may say something significant.

Comment: If A is 0, then B is 0, then \$\nabla \times J = 0\$ but how does that entail that J=0?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Right, strictly speaking the interior volume of a superconductor is not entirely free of the magnetic field, due to the exponentially decaying penetration. By the same logic, you can argue that screening of the electric field due to surface charges only leads to an exponential decay and not a complete compensation. In Sredni's post you can see that rot E is indeed **not compensated** (second graphic) since some field persists in two parts of the ring, oriented such that the total rot E is the same

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy J=0 (or more precisely Delta J=0) follows from the meissner effect.

Comment: If we are looking at the same graphics, they are showing a non-uniform ring with non-uniform resistance. However, the text says, w.r.t. superconducting ring " inside the perfectly conducting material there cannot be any resultant electric field Etot. This means that the surface charge will redistribute in such a way as to produce a coulombian field Ecoul that completely obliterates Eind everywhere inside the ring."

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy All of these special cases with SC ring with or without gap don't change the fact that the total rot E is always constant. Remember even if the SC displaces the E field from within itself, it will enhance the field outside it.

Comment: How can charges in the SC ring, which create a conservative E field,  when superposed upon a rotational E field, yield a net zero field? I could see a changing _current_ creating a E field equal and opposite to an applied rotational E field, but not a charge density.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy This is actually how superconducting mag lev works. The changing magnetic field when you approach a magnet *does* induce a current in the superconducting object, with opposite polarity leading to levitation over the magnet. The current only stops after an opposite magnetic field change happens, i.e. when you take the SC again away from the magnet. However the induced current flows only within the london penetration depth, because the changing magnetic field doesn't reach the interior of the SC due to the meissner effect; i.e. no rot E in the first place.

Comment: So, it seems the correct version of sredni's answer should say, w.r.t. superconducting ring, something like "the current (which is changing due to E_induced) near the surface of the SC will produce a changing counter induced field B_reaction, which in turn will produce an E_reaction field that nearly completely obliterates Eind everywhere inside the ring."

Comment: @tobalt Strictly speaking, that's not quite the entirety of the Meissner effect; that explains why the magnetic field in a superconductor is *constant*, but it does not explain why the magnetic field is *zero* (as opposed to any other number); when the material transitions into the superconducting phase, any magnetic flux that was passing through it previously is expelled (or bundled into flux tubes, for type II superconductors). I'm afraid I don't know the exact explanation for *that* part of the Meissner effect, though. I suspect it's probably strongly nonclassical.

Comment: @Hearth I mentioned that too somewhere in this way too long comment chain. I have omitted the explanation for how the flux present at the NC->SC transition gets frozen in, because it was irrelevant to the question and because I also don't know.